# Empty array bound element disappears on page load

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a simple collection bound to an **observableArray** that is initially empty.  When the page renders it 'sometimes' will show the empty template before the binding kicks in and removes the element. **If you can't see it refresh the page a few times.**  This is happening as below with the container less templates but also happens with normal inline and script tag style templates.

**View:**

```
<div>
  <input data-bind="value: address"/>
  <button data-bind="click: search">Search</button>
</div>
<!-- ko if: list().length > 0 -->
<h5 data-bind="text: list().length"></h5>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko foreach: list -->
    <div class="result" data-bind="text: addr"></div>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {

  var viewModel = function() {
      var self = this;

      self.address = ko.observable("Portland");

      self.list = ko.observableArray();
      self.hasData = function(){return self.list().length > 0;};

      self.search = function() {
              self.list.push({ addr: "Item01" , index: 1 });
              self.list.push({ addr: "Item02" , index: 2 });
              self.list.push({ addr: "Item03" , index: 3 });      
      };
  };

  var vm = new viewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});​
```

I doesn't seem to happen to much on [jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/motowilliams/mx7SM/](http://jsfiddle.net/motowilliams/mx7SM/) or JSBin but does happen locally and when [deployed - http://knockouttest.herokuapp.com/](http://knockouttest.herokuapp.com/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to see the issue in your sample, but a couple choices that you have are:

- use a named template in a `script` tag.  Browsers won't render markup that is in the script tag. You did seem to indicate that you tried it, but you might want to give it another look.
- otherwise, you can wrap it in an element and set `display: none` on it and use `data-bind="visible: true"` as well.  When the page loads it will be hidden and KO will set it to visible when the binding is happening.  Something like:

Here is a sample with the original and the two options that I mentioned and a two second delay in applying the bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mx7SM/2/

Comment: I guess all I needed was some else taking a look at it.  Thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the delay only occurs with the presence of those 2 github gist scripts - which presumably won't be a problem in production? Your binding doesn't occur until the document is ready and they seem to be markedly slowing it down.

Comment: Good call I pulled those gists as they were to show / help folks look at the code w/o having to view the source.  I did confirm that it is still doing it after I pulled those external scripts.  I also made sure my web dev (confirmed in Chrome, FF and IE) tools have cached disabled to force a full grab from the server.